# Chart.js piechart, only have border on the outside of arc

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I have a pie chart made with chart.js and currently i'm wondering if its possible to only have a border for the outside of the circle / arc like so:

[image]

I tried the following configurations but it applies border the to the whole segment.

```
        options: {
          elements: {
              arc: {
                  borderWidth: 0
              }
          }
        }
```

and also:

```
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [male_data , female_data],
            backgroundColor: pieColors1,
            borderWidth: [10, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        }]
    },
```

but this is what im getting:

[image]

Comment: Hi, you just wan to get the pie itself with a transparent background?

Comment: im not quite sure what you mean? i added another photo for you to compare

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to create your own color image (Solid color with white strip on top) and pass it in as a canvas image.

Below is a modified example I've made based on the sample given from the chart.js documentation and a random picture found on the net.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.0.0/Chart.js"></script>
   <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
      
      
<script>
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://www.worktop-express.co.uk/media/gbu0/metro-tiles-white-sparkle-worktops-100717.jpg';
img.onload = function() {
 var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
 var fillPattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 10)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                fillPattern
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(0,0,0,100)',
                'rgba(0,0,0,100)',
                'rgba(0,0,0,100)',
                'rgba(0,0,0,100)',
                'rgba(0,0,0,100)',
                'rgba(0,0,0,100)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 0
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for this. i tried using it but because of another requirement of the canvas (changing sizes) depending on the data, i decided not to use it. thanks anyway.

in the end i used the :before property to make a pseudo circle, a little bit bigger than the pie chart and positioned it behind the pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.0.0/Chart.js"></script>
   <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
      
      
<script>
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://www.worktop-express.co.uk/media/gbu0/metro-tiles-white-sparkle-worktops-100717.jpg';
img.onload = function() {
 var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
 var fillPattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 10)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                fillPattern
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(0,0,0,100)',
                'rgba(0,0,0,100)',
                'rgba(0,0,0,100)',
                'rgba(0,0,0,100)',
                'rgba(0,0,0,100)',
                'rgba(0,0,0,100)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
}
</script>
```